# store.isDirty() is not working properly in Dojo Grid

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have editable row in Dojo grid,i have number of fields like Combobox,Spinner and Textboxes. Am using the gridid.store.isDirty() function to whether any field is modified. But even if i modify any one of the field am getting gridid.store.isDirty() as false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Dojo API](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dojo_data_api_Write_isDirty):

`Given an item, isDirty() returns true if the item has been modified since the last save(). If isDirty() is called with no item argument, then this function returns true if any item has been modified since the last save().`

Check to make sure that you're calling `gridid.store.save()` after your modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I have applied  gridid.store.save() function and added attribute data-dojo-props='intermediateChanges:true' and then I got value

1)gridid.store.save() function Call after loading the Grid
2)Added attribute data-dojo-props='intermediateChanges:true' for my NumberTextBox.
3)After updating the values in the backend(Datbase) called gridid.store.save()